# How to model a many to many relationship in SAP NetWeaver Gateway?

Tags: abap, sap-gateway

*First to say is I did research, this question has already been asked [on SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3832655), but has no answer there. I also tried to google, but after an hour I surrenderd.*

I have two entities, `User`and `Project`. There are two association between them: One is `1:n` saying who the owner of the `Project` is. But there is a second one, the one saying who(which `User`) candidates for which `Project`.

What I also can do is creating the entity in between, called `Candidation`. I allready definded the associations `CandidationToUser` and `CandidationToProject`.

Now can I define such a many to many relation directly without the `Candidation` in between? And after that, how can I implement it? I want to have a `UserSet` on the `Project` and a `ProjectSet` on the `User`. With the `Candidation` in between I only have a `CandidationSet` on both `User` and `Project`

Comment: `Project('1')/CandidatUserSet` and `User('INETPHANTOM')/ProjectCandidatSet` or similar names should work. If you already have the associations you are mentioning, what is missing? The implementation is standard.

Comment: @MikaelG I do not get it. Do I have to add a `CandidateUserSet` to `Project`? (as a Navigationproperty or property?)Or what d you mean?

Comment: I would add it as a NavigationProperty. You could have other relations from a Project so it makes sense to annotate what kind of UserSet you are referring to. In this case, a Candidate UserSet.